# Core Data + keychain for ios account creation for app

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, keychain

I am trying to implement code to create an account for my app.  So far I think I have a good understanding of grabbing the data from textfields are storing it in the Core Data database, but I am not sure how I can store the pin the user creates in the keychain for the app.  I followed [this tutorial](http://josebolanos.wordpress.com/2012/03/16/core-data-passwords-in-keychain/) which creates a class called *Account* which I think is a subclass of *AccountBase*. The Account.m file has a method declaration of:

`- (void)setPassword:(NSString*)aPassword`

Now I'm pretty sure this is the method I want to use to set the "pin" for my application.  I am not sure how I would apply to my *ViewControllerCreate.m* file. The entire method looks like this:

```
- (void)setPassword:(NSString*)aPassword 
{
 if (self.username) [KeychainHelper setPassword:aPassword forKey:self.username];

}
```

So far I have this code in my *ViewControllerCreate.m* file:

```
- (IBAction)createAccount:(id)sender {

// hide keyboard when login button is pressed
[_createUserTextField resignFirstResponder];



// check if create textfields are empty - WRONG

[self checkTextFieldCharLength];

// check if boolean is true / false
if([self checkTextFieldEmpty] == TRUE ) // empty text fields
{
    NSLog(@"Please fill in text fields");
}

else {
    NSLog(@"Thanks for filling out the text fields.");
    // Core Data - retrieve values from text fields and store in database.
    NSManagedObject *newAccount;
    newAccount = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [newAccount setValue:_createUserTextField forKey:@"username"];
    [newAccount setValue:_createEmailTextField forKey:@"email"];
    [newAccount setValue:_createPhoneNumber forKey:@"phoneNumber"];

    // TODO store pin in keychain


    _createUserTextField.text = @"";
    _createEmailTextField.text = @"";
    _createPhoneNumber.text = @"";
    NSError *error;
    [_managedObjectContext save:&error];
    [_createAccountSuccess setHidden:NO];
    NSLog(@"Succefully created account.");
}
}
```

Anyone know how I would go about storing the inputted pin into the keychain when the "create" button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I kind of came up with a solution thanks to the help of @Faded in chat.stackoverflow.com.  The revised code is below:

```
// method to pull text from text fields and store in keychain and account database

- (IBAction)createAccount:(id)sender {

[self checkTextFieldCharLength];

// check if create textfields are empty, check if boolean is true / false
if([self checkTextFieldEmpty] == TRUE ) // empty text fields
{
    NSLog(@"Please fill in text fields");
}

else {
    NSLog(@"Thanks for filling out the text fields.");
    // Core Data - retrieve values from text fields and store in database.
    Account *newAccount;
    newAccount = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [newAccount setValue:_createUserTextField.text forKey:@"username"];
    [newAccount setValue:_createEmailTextField.text forKey:@"email"];
    [newAccount setValue:_createPhoneNumber.text forKey:@"phoneNumber"];

    // TODO store pin in keychain
    [newAccount setPassword:_createPinTextField.text];
    NSLog(@"Pin saved is %@", [newAccount password]);


    _createUserTextField.text = @"";
    _createEmailTextField.text = @"";
    _createPhoneNumber.text = @"";
    _createPinTextField.text = @"";
    NSError *error;
    [_managedObjectContext save:&error];
    [_createAccountSuccess setHidden:NO];
    NSLog(@"Succefully created account.");
}
```

}